# Physical interpretation of transport, mutual and relative kinetic energy?

Tags: energy, lagrangian-formalism, constrained-dynamics

Let $u_{ik}$ denote the $i^{th}$ component of the position vector of the $k^{th}$ particle. Then kinetic energy of the system of $N$ particles is given by:
$$T=\frac{1}{2}\sum^N_{k=1}\sum^3_{i=1}m_k\dot u_{ik}\dot u_{ik}$$
Next, since $u_{ik}=U_{ik}(q_1, ... , q_n, t)$, we may write,
$$\dot u_{ik}=\frac{\partial U_{ik}}{\partial t}+\sum^n_{s=1}\frac{\partial U_{ik}}{\partial q_s}\dot q_s$$
This gives rise to three terms.

First term:
$$T_0=\frac{1}{2}\sum^N_{k=1}\sum^3_{i=1}m_k\left(\frac{\partial U_{ik}}{\partial t}\right)^2$$
which is the transport kinetic energy.

Second term: 
$$T_1=\sum^n_{s=1}\sum^N_{k=1}\sum^3_{i=1}m_k\left(\frac{\partial U_{ik}}{\partial t}\right)\left(\frac{\partial U_{ik}}{\partial q_s}\right)\dot q_s$$
which is the mutual kinetic energy.

Third term:
$$T_2=\frac{1}{2}\sum^n_{r=1}\sum^n_{s=1}\sum^N_{k=1}\sum^3_{i=1}m_k\left(\frac{\partial U_{ik}}{\partial q_s}\right)\left(\frac{\partial U_{ik}}{\partial q_r}\right)\dot q_s\dot q_r$$
which is the relative kinetic energy.

I can see that $T_2$ is the term that is left when explicit dependence on time is suppressed while $T_0$ is the term left when the generalised coordinates $q_1, ..., q_n$ are frozen. I would like to know if there is some physical interpretation of these terms (for example for a general planar motion, we have two terms in kinetic energy which are translational and rotational KE).

Another reason I am asking for physical interpretation of these terms is that I think it will help me understand this statement:

> The restriction is made here to a system which does not undergo
>   overall motion so that its kinetic energy is reduced to the only
>   quadratic term $T_2 = T_2(\dot q)$ in the generalized velocities.

By @PM2Ring's comment, I know that overall motion means no motion of the center of mass. How does it imply that $T_0$ and $T_1$ become zero, or more specifically, that $\left(\frac{\partial U_{ik}}{\partial t}\right)=0$?

Comment: If you have a bottle full of gas sitting on your lab bench, the bottle (and its gas) has zero overall motion (in the lab frame).

Comment: @PM2Ring Ah okay. So is it like the particles themselves are in motion but the center of mass isn't for it to be called no overall motion?